# Почему RayCast видит только коллайдер объекта из которого выходит? с# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пускаю луч в 4 направлениях (вверх, вниз, влево и вправо), чтобы определить какие объекты окружают текущий объект. Однако, все четыре направления выдают только один результат - данные текущего объекта. Почему так? Коллайдеры висят на всех объектах (из которого луч в том числе), дочерних объектов и коллайдеров никаких нет. Слои, положение в плоскости и прочее прочее - все одинаковое. Debug.DrawRay рисует лучи как надо. Ниже код:

```
private Vector2[] castDir = new Vector2[] { Vector2.up, Vector2.down, Vector2.left, Vector2.right }; //Направления для лучей проверки объектов рядом

RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, castDir, 10f);
        if (hit.collider != null) {
            //Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, castDir, Color.red, 100f);
            Debug.Log(hit.collider);
            return hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
```

Через for отправляю по всем 4 направлениям, но выдает только текущий объект.

Comment: Либо используй layermask и исключай слой объекта, из которого делаешь рейкаст, тогда у тебя его не будет в результате. Либо проходись по результатам рейкаста и исключай оттуда свой коллайдер.

Comment: Как я могу использовать layermask, если все объекты одинаковые? (Делаю игру Три в ряд) - тогда все будут либо видимые, либо невидимые..

Comment: Я же тебе, специально для такого случая, второй вариант предложил.

Comment: А как это можно сделать с помощью кода? А то единственный вариант какой я пока нашел и работает - отключить Queries Start In Colliders в настройках проекта..

Comment: Берешь все свои хиты, которые возвращает рейкаст, проходишься по ним, исключаешь оттуда свой коллайдер. Но кажется мне, что ты что-то не то делаешь, раз тебе рейкаст в данном случае нужен. Всё поле в три в ряд - это граф, либо двойной массив ячеек, ты можешь не рейкаст делать, а просто проверять что содержится в ячейке выше, ниже, правее, левее, по диагонали и т.д.

Comment: Ну, если только соседние ячейки проверять, то можно, но если нужно дальше всю линию проверить, то варианта, кроме луча, я пока не нашел. Ладно, пока работает как надо, а дальше если это будет мешать - буду искать уже другие пути. В любом случае - спасибо за подсказки )